# Counting solutions to $i_1 + i_2 + \ldots + i_n = K$ where no variable is equal to $1$.

Tags: combinatorics

I am dealing with a problem that I have to count how many ways I can add $i_1 + i_2 + \ldots + i_n = K$ (each $i_j$ is a non-negative integer and $K$ is a positive integer) such that no $i_j$ can ever take the value of $1$.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Don't you know "stars and bars" ? Or is your difficulty with "no $i_j$
 can ever take the value of $1$" ?
.

Comment: See [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and/or [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: @trueblueanil Yes, my difficulty lies in the latter

Answer (score 3):

The generating function for an individual $i_k$ is

$$1+\frac{x^2}{1-x}=\frac{1-x+x^2}{1-x}$$

You then want the coefficient of $x^K$ in

$$\left(\frac{1-x+x^2}{1-x}\right)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us first count solutions which have exactly $r$ variables that are nonzero. There are $\binom nr$ ways to choose the nonzero variables. Choosing the values for the nonzero variables is equivalent to counting the number of nonnegative integer solutions to the below equation:
$$
x_1+\dots+x_{r}=K\\
\text{such that } x_i\ge 2\text{ for each $i\in \{1,\dots,r\}$}
$$
This is further equivalent to counting nonnegative integer solutions to $y_1+\dots+y_{r}=K-2r$, since you can subtract two from each variable. We have now reduced this to a usual instance of stars and bars, so the number of solutions in this case is $\binom{K-2r+r-1}{K-2r}=\binom{K-r-1}{K-2r}$.

To get the final answer, you sum over all possible values of $r$:
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{\min(n,\lfloor K/2\rfloor)}\binom{n}{r}\binom{K-r-1}{K-2r}
$$